# Automatically decline UAC prompt for specific binary and/or path

Tags: uac

Is it possible to automatically decline UAC prompts from a specific binary or path ? (As if user clicked "no" or as if GPO was set to automatically decline)

Answer (score 0):

[RunAsInvoker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/dd638389(v=ws.10)) compatibility shim seems to do the trick.

> The RunAsInvoker compatibility fix enables an application to start by
>   using the token inherited from the parent process. The RunAsInvoker
>   fix overrules both installer detection and manifest processing, and
>   will determine the elevation state for the entire application after it
>   is applied.
>
> The RunAsAdmin compatibility fix should be considered as a possible
>   resolution if the application prompts for elevation, but can also run
>   successfully as a Standard User. If the application is elevating
>   because of installer detection, you should use the
>   SpecificNonInstaller compatibility fix. If the application is
>   elevating the current context because the developer included a
>   manifest specifying the requireAdministrator run-level, then this
>   compatibility fix should be used. This fix specifies that the
>   application does not require elevation.